# How to use angular variables into laravel functions in a blade template?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using a combination of laravel and angular.js . For angular I changed the interpolateProvider symbols to <% %>. For laravel i am using the standard {{ }} symbols.

Now to use an angular variable in my view and pass this to a function in laravel.

I tried this:

```
{{ route('getEdit', ['id' => <% loop.id %>]) }}
```

Where loop.id  is from an ng-repeat from angular. And route is the routing function from laravel.

This gives an error :

*syntax error, unexpected '<'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass javascript variable to PHP, you will need to use Ajax.

create an action in a controller called getRoute, `post [/get-route/{route}]`

**PHP**

```
public function getRoute($request, $route) {
    return route($route, $request->input('params'));
}
```

and make a request to this route with your route name and a params object :

**Jquery**

```
$.post('{{ route('getRoute') }}', {params: [{id : loop.id}]}, function(data) {
    console.log(data); //should output the route with javascript variable loop.id
});
```

or using angular :

**Angular**

```
<script>
   var getRoute = '{{ route('getRoute') }}'; //Define your route inside a PHP file
</script>

$http.post(getRoute, {params: [{id : loop.id}]}).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); //should output the route with javascript variable loop.id
});
```

Comment: OP: "For angular I changed the interpolateProvider symbols to <% %>". I think they already did this.